# Laravel local server not responding even after restarting

Tags: python, laravel

I encountered this situation while woring with Laravel. I was trying to execute a python script on the server using this command

```
$result = shell_exec("python " . app_path(). "\http\controllers\py\yitdosproxy\yitdos.py "."2>&1");
```

If the **yitdos.py** file is small, i.e "print(1)", it executed successfully. But when I put my main script (about 15000 lines of python), the server just keep loading. 
My server was running on **127.0.0.1:8000**
What confused me at this point is, even if I restart the server, I cannot access to **127.0.0.1:8000** anymore. It just keep loading when I request to it. Using Postman was giving the same result.
HOWEVER, when I change the port, it worked again. (I knew it because I have an index file in "/". But when I accessed to the route where the python file is executed, the same thing happended again.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing your laravel cache files and run again.

```html
Php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score 0):

I've the same problem before. What I do is using Ajax Call to a php function which will execute the script, it won't freeze your page and make it easier to handle

Comment: Well the main problem is the code just execute at an undesirable amount of time. Ajax calls might fix the UI and user's interaction problem, but the real issue is the server just keep running and cause insufficient bandwidth